# How do I destroy the Blueprint Brain Tank?

Tags: psychonauts

I'm a few hours in to Psychonauts and I'm getting mauled by a huge tank powered by

> Dogan's brain.

How the heck do I beat this thing?
[image: Blueprint Brain Tank]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, I just got it.

- Hide from its view (behind pillars) until it stands up on its back wheels.
- Lock onto it and fire at its exposed underside, which will turn it on its back.
- While it's on its back, smack it around until it turns back over.
- Repeat until the tank is destroyed

After the tank is destroyed, you'll have to fight the brain itself (all good boss battles have multiple stages, right)?  The brain will shoot out a line of light that will damage Raz when he walks into it.

- After spinning twice, the lazer will slow down
- Jump over the slowed lazer
- While in above the brain, do a ground pound onto it
- Repeat until the brain is destroyed

[image: Hiding from the tank]
[image: Tank on its back]
[image: The brain]
[image: Brain attacking]

Comment: Cruller will explain most of this if you invoke the bacon (I landed on SE because it's still damn hard — blasted brain tank).